# ld does not link OpenGL on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, gcc

```
gcc -lGL -lGLU -lglut light.c 
/tmp/ccfuthSi.o: In function `init':
light.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
light.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `glShadeModel'
light.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `glMaterialfv'
light.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `glMaterialfv'
light.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `glLightfv'
light.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `glEnable'
light.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `glEnable'
light.c:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `glEnable'
/tmp/ccfuthSi.o: In function `display':
light.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `glClear'
light.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `glutSolidSphere'
light.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `glFlush'
/tmp/ccfuthSi.o: In function `reshape':
light.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `glViewport'
light.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
light.c:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
light.c:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
light.c:(.text+0x217): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
light.c:(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
light.c:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
/tmp/ccfuthSi.o: In function `main':
light.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `glutInit'
light.c:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
light.c:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
light.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
light.c:(.text+0x2a9): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
light.c:(.text+0x2ba): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
light.c:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
light.c:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
light.c:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
```

As you can see, i pass the required parameters to the gcc. Why it does not work? Linux Mint 12.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It really is a FAQ (and has been asked and answered many times here). Order of arguments matters when linking. Libraries should go last (and in the good order). You should run

```
gcc -Wall -g light.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut -o light
```

Comment: NB: Being unfamiliar with glut, I am not entirely sure of the order of the libraries. You should find out the correct one!

Comment: In case of shared library systems, it does not matter, since glut already has all its symbol housekeeping done and you are only trying to satisfy light.c's.