# Compiler unable to link/find GLFW

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to run a modified program that can be found at [cpp-pointcloud.cpp](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/librealsense/html/cpp-pointcloud_8cpp_source.html). I am having difficulties getting it to build.

As it is now my file structure is:

```
-pointcloud.cpp
-librealsense/
    -examples
        -example.hpp
```

And I am building it with the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 pointcloud.cpp -lrealsense -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -o ir
```

The imports of the pointcloud.cpp file are as follows:

```
 // License: Apache 2.0. See LICENSE file in root directory.
 // Copyright(c) 2015 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

 #include <librealsense/rs.hpp>
 #include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>

 #include "librealsense/examples/example.hpp"

 #include <chrono>
 #include <vector>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
```

And they are:

```
#pragma once

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
```

In the example.hpp file.

My issue is that it cannot seem to find the glfw files. I get a bunch of errors like:

```
pointcloud.cpp:(.text+0xdf5): undefined reference to `glPopMatrix'
```

Which is bizarre to me as I'm confident that i've installed the GLFW3 package. And I believed that includes that use the angle brackets search for installed packages on your operating system.

I've ran this command successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev
```

I tried adding

```
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

to the pointcloud.cpp file but it actually gave me more errors!

I miss be misunderstanding something conceptually here, so if any of you could point me in the right direction that would be great thanks.

Comment: Headers are no libraries. Learn about the differences (any good beginners' textbook should cover it).

Comment: Also see [ld does not link OpenGL on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8553462/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You have to link GLFW with `pkg-config` cf **[How do I link GLFW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049769/how-do-i-link-glfw)**

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags glfw3` -o foo foo.c `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3`
```

you can locate the libraries  using `locate` or `whereis` ( update database before with `sudo updatedb` , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194088/how-to-check-if-a-shared-library-is-installed ) or `find` ( /www.lifewire.com/uses-of-linux-command-find-2201100 ) i.e.

```
sudo updatedb  ( may take some time ... )
locate libglfw
```

or

```
sudo find /usr/lib -name '*libglfw*'
```

possibly also check all dependencies required for `libglfw` using `ldd`